# Is it bad to have an embedded table view?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I wonder if there is any downside in having an embedded table view?

I have a navigation controller VC that leads to another VC which is my app's "main/root" VC.

Inside that VC I have a container view which holds a table view.

The table view then has more segues leading to other VCs. Is this a bad setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is nothing bad to having an embedded table view. In fact, I do it all the time. I just think it is a lot easier to make a better looking layout in your app and there is nothing different when setting up a detail view controller for the table view whether it is embedded or not.

Comment: Thanks. That was exactly why I went for an embedded segue. Much easier to setup my layout the way I wanted

Answer (score 1):

Apple has certain recommendations for this. Essentially if the table view takes up the entire screen it's more efficient to use a UITableViewController. However the overhead is not too bad at all. Here's the relevant link:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/CreateConfigureTableView/CreateConfigureTableView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH6-SW10

In particular see the section:

> Creating a Table View Programmatically
>
> If you choose not to use UITableViewController for table view
>   management, you must replicate what this class gives you “for free.”

Here's one concrete example of an annoying detail that must be handled by you:

```
class CustomViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var optionsTableView: UITableView!
    // ... later that same day ...
    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        optionsTableView.flashScrollIndicators()
        if let path = lastSelectedPath {
            optionsTableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(path, animated: true)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not bad. But if the whole screen were to be covered by the table view, I would definitely go with a table view controller just for simplicity and the stuff you get fro free. Some times though, you need more flexibility, and an embedded table view is the only way to go. For instance, consider this example:

[image]